# How to solve the complexity for T(n+1)=T(n)+logn

Tags: math, time-complexity

so I have this recursion:

```
T(1)=a, n=1
T(n+1)=T(n)+logn, n>=1
```

When I resolve by substitution I get this expression:

```
T(n)=log(n-1)...+log(n-k)+T(n-k)
```

(K is n-1)

Then,

```
T(n)=log(n-1)...+log(1)+T(1)
```

log(1)=0 and T(1)=a

From there, I don't know how to obtain an expression such that the complexity is O(n^2) [This is required in the exercise]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have figured out yourself, `T(n) = log(n) + ... + log(1) = log(n!)`.
It is well knows that this is in `O(nlog(n))`. to show this we can present a higher and a lower bound:
log(n) + ... + log(1) <= log(n) + ... + log(n) = n * log(n), thus `T(n) = O(n * log(n))`.
log(n) + ... + log(1) >= log(n) + ... + log(n/2) >= log(n/2) + ... + log(n/2) = n/2*log(n/2) = n/2*log(n) - n/2 = Ω(n*log(n)).

Thus, we can conclude that `T(n) = Θ(n * log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

As you found `T(n) = log(n!)`. You can use [Stirling formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and replace `n!` with `(n/e)^n * \sqrt{2\pi n}`. Hence, you will get `T(n) ~ n log(n/e) + 0.5 log(2 pi * n) = Theta(n log(n))`.